# Meteor Flow Router Dynamic Template

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I've been working on my on meteor app. Now it will be great if my maincontent on the mainpage is dynamic. I got this code:

**main.html**

```
<head>
  <title>Taskmanager</title>
</head>
<body>
{{> navBar}}
{{> mainlayout}}
</body>
```

**mainlayout.html**

```
<template name="mainlayout">
<main>
{{> Template.dynamic template=main}}
</main>
</template>
```

**routes.js**

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
name: 'home',
action: function() {
BlazeLayout.render('mainlayout', {main: 'noteOverview'});
}
});
```

**noteoverview.html**

```
<template name="noteOverview">
 <div class="container">
  <h3>Latest Tasks</h3>
 </div>
</template>
```

When i open the page, the mainlayout doesn't load the noteoverview.html in. Do i miss something? Thanx for any help!

**SOLVED:**
I forgot to add the package: kadira:blaze-layout....stupid fault

Comment: I would suggest uploading your whole project to GitHub - it looks like it's in an early stage anyway

Comment: I fixed it, stupid from my side. I forgot to add the package: kadira:blaze-layout. Thanx for help

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have a navbar on your template.

Maybe the `<h3>Latest Tasks</h3>` on your notesOverview template is hiding behind the navbar.

Try adding

`body{
margin-top:80px;
}`

to your app's stylesheet.